# How to find the similar $\Phi$-similar function?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

Given the IVP: 
$x'=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}-x-y, x(0)=x_0$ 
$y'=\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}-x+y, y(0)=y_0$

We are supposed to solve this ODE by finding a function $\Phi: \mathbb{R}^+ \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^2 \backslash \lbrace 0 \rbrace$ of $C^1$ such as 
$r'=1-r, r(0)=r_0$ 
$\phi = 1, \phi(0)=\phi_0$ 
is $\Phi$-similar to the given vectorfield. I have a hard time finding this and understanding how this is supposed to help me with the ODE.

Comment: Transform to polar coordinates.

Comment: Is there a sign error somewhere? Currently $rr'=xx'+yy'=r-x^2-2xy+y^2$ and $r^2\phi'=xy'-yx'=-x^2+2xy+y^2$.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**:

Tranform to polar coordinates with $x=r\cos(\phi)$ and $y=r\sin(\phi)$.  Then, we have

$$x'=\cos(\phi)r'-r\sin(\phi)\phi'$$

and

$$y'=\sin(\phi)r'+r\cos(\phi)\phi'$$

Then, we can see that

$$x'=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}-x-y\implies \cos(\phi)r'-r\sin(\phi)\phi'=\cos(\phi)-r\cos(\phi)-r\sin(\phi)$$

and

$$y'=\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}-x+y\implies \sin(\phi)r'+r\cos(\phi)\phi'=\sin(\phi)-r\cos(\phi)+r\sin(\phi)$$

Can you finish now by solving simultneously to $r'$ and $\phi'$?